# Unique "clicked" at my Simplenews Newslwetter

Tags: drupal, google-analytics, drupal-7, newsletter

I send newsletters from my drupal-7 website using Simplenews Newsletter module.
The newsletters consist of images that have links to my page. What I want, is to have a unique clicked measure. What I currently use is adding the following code:

```
?utm_source=newsletter_june_2016&amp;utm_medium=email&amp;utm_campaign=newsletter_june_2016
```

and then logging into Google Analytics, at Acquisition -> Campaigns -> All Campaigns and check the value of newsletter_june_2016 as an example.
But this method doesn't provide unique click for my links. If I click twice on a link, the counter gets increased by two, and Ι can't tell how many of my site's users have actually clicked the link, only how many times were the links clicked.
Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Add a parameter that's unique per user and store that as a custom dimension (you could even use the GA clientid to recognize a recurring user when you set it if it's present in the incoming url).

Comment: How do you add the client id at the utm code?There is not such parameter for utm. Is there an example, or can you show at the example I posted?

Comment: No, there is no such utm parameter. You'd need to catch the client id when users subscribe, then use a custom GET parameter and implement the Javascript logic to set this as the id in your tracker yourself.  If that's to much work add a random id that's unqiue per user, store in a custom dimension and simply count the unqiue pageviews for that dimension.

Comment: My site has already too many users, so I can't use your first suggestion. I think I am gonna choose the second one, but I don't really understand how to make this work. Each user is stored in my database with a different id. Should I use that? And how will I set it at my newsletter? I am not that used to GA